# Generating captcha image fails due font family file missing on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I have created my custom captcha image, which is not rendering due to missing font on server.

```
private const string FontFamily = "Arial";   //this one works

private const string FontFamily = "Rockwell";   //this one is not existing on server
```

How do i provide the font file to the application to use my custom font family from file?
at the moment i have my function as:

```
using (Font font = new Font(FontFamily, 1f)){
//rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Do you need to have a font working with the application or would it be enough to just install the font on the server?

Comment: I have no access to server except ftp. So i need to add the font to application, but have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your custom captcha drawing method, but you generally have the function [drawString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/19sb1bw6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), where you can add your newly registered font via a [PrivateFontCollection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) to write text with. An example in VB would be:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Public Class clsUtility
Public Shared Function GetFontPic(ByVal Fontpath As String, ByVal Text As String) As System.Drawing.Bitmap
Dim width As Integer = 620
Dim height As Integer = 30
Dim FontImage As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(FontImage)
g.Clear(Color.White)
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
Dim pointF As New PointF(10,0)
Dim FontSize As Integer = 24
Dim solidBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
Dim privateFontCollection As New PrivateFontCollection()
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(Fontpath) ' load font from file
Dim thisFont As FontFamily = privateFontCollection.Families(0)
Dim regFont As New Font(thisFont, FontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel) ' Create a new font
g.DrawString(Text, regFont, solidBrush, pointF) ' Using the font write the text using the font style
Return FontImage
End Function
```

Source: http://www.tutorialsasp.net/uncategorized/loading-and-previewing-fonts-from-files-in-aspnet/